# ORMLite on Android throws an exception when creating a table with a column of the type enum and a default value

Tags: java, android, ormlite

One of my business objects got a member of the type CommunicationMedium which is an enumeration.

```
public enum CommunicationMedium {
    EMAIL,
    PHONE,
    MOBILE,
    FACSIMILE,
    HOMEPAGE
}
```

The business object called CommunicationData is annotated like this.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName="store_communication_data")
public class CommunicationData{

    public static final String STORE_ID ="store_id";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "store_communication_data";
    public static final String MEDIUM_COLUMN_NAME = "medium";
    public static final String VALUE_COLUMN_NAME = "value";

    @DatabaseFieldSimple(canBeNull=false, columnName=STORE_ID)
    @DatabaseFieldForeign(foreign=true)
    private Store store;

    @DatabaseFieldSimple(canBeNull=false, columnName=MEDIUM_COLUMN_NAME, defaultValue="CommunicationMedium.EMAIL")
    @DatabaseFieldOther(dataType=DataType.ENUM_STRING)
    private CommunicationMedium communicationMedium;        

    @DatabaseFieldSimple(canBeNull=false, columnName=VALUE_COLUMN_NAME)
    private String value; 
    ...
}
```

When accessing the database helper the first time following exception is thrown when the table for the `CommunicationData` class should get created. There seem to be a problem with the default value for the `medium` column.

```
java.sql.SQLException: SQL statement failed: CREATE TABLE `store_communication_data` (`medium` __ormlite__ no default value string was specified , `store_id` INTEGER NOT NULL , `value` VARCHAR NOT NULL ) 
     at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
     at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.doStatements(TableUtils.java:458)
     at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.doCreateTable(TableUtils.java:436)
     at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTable(TableUtils.java:223)
     at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTable(TableUtils.java:53)
     ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Problems executing Android statement: CREATE TABLE `store_communication_data` (`medium` __ormlite__ no default value string was specified , `store_id` INTEGER NOT NULL , `value` VARCHAR NOT NULL ) 
     at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
     at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.runUpdate(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:71)
     at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.doStatements(TableUtils.java:452)
     ...
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "string": syntax error: , while compiling: CREATE TABLE `store_communication_data` (`medium` __ormlite__ no default value string was specified , `store_id` INTEGER NOT NULL , `value` VARCHAR NOT NULL ) 
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_compile(Native Method)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compile(SQLiteProgram.java:110)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1026)
     ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crap.  This is a bug that was introduced with the `columnDefinition` feature in version 4.26 and was fixed in 4.27.    If you use the `@DatabaseFieldOther` annotation without specifying the `columnDefinition`, you will trigger this unfortunate bug.  You can work around it for now @Flo by adding a `columnDefinition` value:

```
@DatabaseFieldSimple(canBeNull = false, columnName = MEDIUM_COLUMN_NAME, defaultValue = "EMAIL")
@DatabaseFieldOther(dataType = DataType.ENUM_STRING, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'EMAIL' NOT NULL")
private CommunicationMedium communicationMedium;
```

The [bug](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3419779&group_id=297653&atid=1255989#) was added to our bug tracking system and I've fixed it in version 4.27.
Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I think the work around is ok for me at the moment.